# removing exponential notation in text data

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing

I have three text data (x,y,z);
x=

```
0.230470334533783E+07 
0.230470334324697E+07
```

y=

```
-0.487481717139422E+07 
-0.487481717040853E+07
```

z=

```
0.339518702164184E+07 
0.339518702104482E+07
```

I need to remove exponential notation "E" in all data (with 4 decimal points) for three text files. Then I need to combine the three data in one text file like;

combined_data:

```
2304703.3453  -4874817.1714  3395187.0216 
2304703.3432  -4874817.1704  3395187.0210
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `perl` (to parse the numbers) and `paste`:

```
$ paste x y z | perl -lane 'print join (" ", map {sprintf("%.4f", $_)} @F)'
2304703.3453 -4874817.1714 3395187.0216
2304703.3432 -4874817.1704 3395187.0210
```

`paste` combines the files:

```
$ paste x y z
0.230470334533783E+07   -0.487481717139422E+07  0.339518702164184E+07
0.230470334324697E+07   -0.487481717040853E+07  0.339518702104482E+07
```

`perl`'s `-a` splits the input into the array `@F`. Then  I use `map` to apply `sprintf("%.4f")` to each element of the array, and then combine back them using `join()`.

Comment: Just for the sake of golfing it a bit, you could also just change the separator instead of using `join()`: `paste x y z | perl -lane '$,=" ";print(map {sprintf("%.4f", $_)} @F)'`